# Adding additional text above y-label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a big plot to compare forecast-models. But how can one add additional text to a label? For example this is one of the plots that I need additional text beside the y-label.

```
(qplot(y = VaR90_n_roll1, x = 507:1006, geom = 'line')
                     + geom_line(color = 'green')
                     + geom_point(aes(x = 507:1006, y = sp500_logreturns[507:1006]))
                     + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.065,0.05))
                     + labs(y = c('Log returns', 
                            'Model 1'), x = '')
                     + ggtitle("")
                     + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

Which gives me this: 
[image]

But I need this: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It this what you are looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(y = expression(atop(bold(Model~1), scriptstyle(Log~returns))))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That looks fine to me, but how do I change the font to bold in the 'outer' label?

Comment: You have two options now with @user20350's alternative

Comment: It's getting better and better. Now, lastly, is it possible to make it bigger (like the standard ggtitle)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant without making the "Model" bigger.

Comment: I think there was a disconnect between your written question and the image you wanted! But this seems to fit the bill?

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you!